# Insert problem in a Filemaker datetime field

Tags: insert, timestamp, filemaker

I need to enter a value in a Filemaker table, in a field that should be DATETIME or TIMESTAMP.I do not know Filemaker at all, but I do this simple query

```
INSERT INTO RadioGestInterface (Data_Ora_Prestazione) VALUES ('2019-02-14 11:13:11')
```

But I always get this error:
**ERROR [HY000] [FileMaker][FileMaker] FQL0013/(1:62): Incompatible types in assignment.**
Where am I wrong?

Comment: Are you using FileMaker as a data source, or are you doing this inside the FileMaker client?

Comment: I have a c # program that accesses another company's FileMaker database with odbc drivers.

Comment: What is the data type of the fields in FileMaker that you are inserting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [**FileMaker®16 SQL Reference**](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/16/en/fm16_sql_reference.pdf) document, page 24:

> For ODBC and JDBC applications, FileMaker accepts the ODBC/JDBC format
>   date, time, and timestamp constants in braces ({}).
>
> **Examples**
>
> - {D '2019-06-05'}
> - {T '14:35:10'}
> - {TS '2019-06-05 14:35:10'}
>
> FileMaker allows the type specifier (D, T, TS) to be in upper case or
>   lower case. You may use any number of spaces after the type specifier,
>   or even omit the space.
>
> FileMaker also accepts SQL-92 syntax ISO date and time formats with no
>   braces.
>
> **Examples**
>
> - DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'
> - TIME 'HH:MM:SS'
> - TIMESTAMP 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'

Answer (score 0):

When imported a string into a TIMESTAMP field, FileMaker accepts a string formatted as '02/04/2024 16:32:34'. The following code converts from the format you used to the necessary format:

```
    import datetime

    the_dt = datetime.strptime(ts_str1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    ts_str2 = the_dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```